# Add libraries into Qt5

Tags: c++, qt

I just downloaded some kde libraries from the inqlude website. Those are archives of headers and c++ files. I read through some websites looking for a way to integrate those files as libraries in Qt without any success. So, here are some questions:

- Do I have to copy those files directly in my Qt project to use them?
- Is there a way to add them as Qt standard libraries so that I can call them as any Qt or Windows libraries?

I am using Qt5.3 OpenGL with MSVC2013 compiler on a Windows 8 x64 bits platform.

Thank you.

Update:

Hi,

I found a KDE installer for Windows that takes care of loading and linking the required packages for the KDE libraries. So, I can now call KDE header from my Qt project.

I still have a question. The include I have to make looks this way

```
#include <KDE/include/kApplication.h>
```

and I would like to write only

```
#include <kApplication.h>
```

like I saw in KDE applications. How can I get that? Is there any ways?

Thanks!

Update:

Hi,

I resolved the path problem with the INCLUDEPATH directive in the .pro file.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-2.3/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html but if it is just sources, you will have to build the libs yourself, or find prebuilt binaries

Comment: It's not compiled? Did you try to compile it and follow these instructions? http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-2.3/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html

Comment: @ddriver Please post this as an answer, or I can so it can be accepted.

Comment: @danielfranca Please post this as an answer, or I can so it can be accepted.

Comment: @JonathanMee danielfranca's comment is certainly not fit to be posted as an answer, he's only asking questions to the OP.

Comment: @JonathanMee - SO no longer accepts such answers, i.e. link-only. Posting such as comments is the proper format.

Comment: @ddriver I suggest you put the relevant sections in your answer and cite the source with a link.